# Exchange 2010 mailbox actions audit

Tags: exchange-2010

Can somebody please link me to or provide me with instructions on how to enable auditing on all Exchange 2010 mailboxes so we can view when somebody accesses a mailbox that they are not the owner of.

Additionally, what sort of performance impact will this have on an environment with 200 mailboxes? How much disk space will these logs potentially use?

Also, how can I specify exactly where I want the logs to be stored and set them to rotate after a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each mailbox has separate auditing options for administrators, delegates and the mailbox owner - all of which are disabled by default. You can view the various auditing properties by issuing `Get-Mailbox jsmith |fl *Audit*` in the Exchange Management Shell. To enable auditing on a particular mailbox, use the cmdlet `Set-Mailbox jsmith -AuditEnabled $True`.

To view the logs use the `Search-MailboxAuditLog` cmdlet, whose options are documented [over on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff522360.aspx). An example cmdlet to run to view the audit logs is  `Search-MailboxAuditLog jsmith -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate -StartDate 1/1/2010 -EndDate 12/31/2010 -ResultSize 2000`. This will restrict the selection criteria to reports for the user *jsmith*, only show admin and delegate actions between 1st January 2010 and 31st December 2010 with a maximum of 2000 results.

Alternatively, you can view a much more sensible and human-readable version of these logs in the Exchange Control Panel under *Auditing Reports* and then *Run a non-owner mailbox access report*.

Notice that auditing can be enabled for three access types - admin, delegate, and owner. The amount of logging that is generated will depend on which access types you audit. Obviously owner would be the most log intensive and is one you'd probably want to leave turned off.

The logs are stored in the mailbox, you have no control over where to store them, but you can set a retention limit on them to reduce the storage overhead.

[Source for most of this information](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-mailbox-audit-logging).

Comment: Paul, we advise against answers here where the actual solution is a link off-site. Please consider pasting the relevant information into your answer here - that way, if the site you linked to ever goes down the solution is not lost.

Comment: Regardless, I appreciate the reply. Wasn't sure I was going to get one to this question...thanks!

Comment: I've copied most of the important information into this post, so it doesn't require off-site linkage any more to find the actual solution.